# How can I select a range of columns or one column by name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the `'Country Name'` columns and also the years from 2006 to 2015.

This is what the df looks like:

[image: GPD dataframe]

I've tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
GPD.loc[:,'Country Name',['2006':'2015']]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) and unpacking:

```
GPD.loc[:, ['Country Name', *range(2006, 2015+1)]]
```

Or if the years are strings:

```
GPD.loc[:, ['Country Name', *map(str, range(2006, 2015+1))]]
```

Or a double slicing:

```
GPD.loc[:, ['Country Name']+list(GPD.loc[:, '2006':'2015'])]
```